# input-group with a prepended element in the middle?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to have a prepend element between two input elements.
I can solve it with extra css but that not what I wanted.

Is there a solution with **bootstrap only** and **no extra css** code?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="input-group input-group-sm m-4 w-50">
  <input class="form-control" type="text">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is simple.

Just use the classes `input-group-prepend` and `input-group-append` together.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="input-group input-group-sm w-50 m-4">
  <input class="form-control" type="text">
  <div class="input-group-prepend input-group-append">
    <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control"></input>
</div>
```